# FLUTTER: How do I get the docID from a flutter querySnapshot stream

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream

How do I record the document ID and pass it into the Streambuilder's return system.
**Stream**

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> _stream1 = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("notifications")
      .where("parentUID", isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
      .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
      .snapshots();
```

**StreamBuilder Code**
The streambuilder returns a widget I created called adminNotifCard and it takes 3 parameters, and I want to save the docID for each result in the query, however, data.id doesnt work, I know its becuase it is a querysnapshot but how do I save it in a parameter

```
               Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 30,
                        right: 30,
                      ),
                      child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection("notifications")
                            .where("parentUID",
                                isEqualTo:
                                    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                            .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
                            .snapshots(),
                        builder: (BuildContext context,
                            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            return Text('Something went wrong');
                          }

                          if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                              ConnectionState.waiting) {
                            return Text("Loading");
                          }
                          return Column(
                            children: snapshot.data!.docs.map(
                              (DocumentSnapshot document) {
                                Map<String, dynamic> data =
                                    document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;


                                //HERE IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS


                                return adminNotifCard(
                                  text1: data['notifTitle'],
                                  text2: data['notifNotes'],
                                  //How do I get the doc ID of the result and put in the custom widget
                                  docID: ___ ,
                                );
                              },
                            ).toList(),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
```

**Image of Firestore database**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Each doc has an id property, you can access like this:

```dart
 
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: FirebaseRepository()
      .db
      .collection("notifications")
      .where("parentUID", isEqualTo: 'userUid')
      .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (xtx, snap) {
    if (snap.hasError) {
      return Text('Something went wrong');
    }

    if (snap.connectionState ==
        ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return Text("Loading");
    }
    snap.data!.docs.forEach(
      (element) {
        // heres your data
        element.id;
      },
    );
    return Column(
      children: snap.data!.docs
          .map(
            (e) => ListTile(
              title: Text(e.id),
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
    );
  },
)
```